# Random Choice in Python

Tags: python

I need to generate a random item from a list that is based on an user-mported file. When I use random.choice() for the file the program returns the entire list. I've posted the code below. I need it to single out one object that I can then utilize.

```
import random
file=input("Please enter file name: ")
fhandle=open(file, 'r')
wfile=fhandle.read().split('\n')
words=[]
words.append(wfile)
random=random.choice(words)
print(random)
```

Comment: You are overwriting the `random` module you are importing, dont use reserved words for variables.

Comment: @Erfan While that is a bad idea, it doesn't explain what OP is seeing

Comment: Don't forget to `close()`

Comment: @andreis11 or better yet, use `with`

Comment: @John Coleman, not enough upvote posibilities

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the whole list `wfile` as one *single* element to the `words` list.

You can use `words.extend(wfile)` instead to add all elements of `wfile` to `words`.

Read more about `append` and `extend` [in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like:

```
import random, os
file = input("Please enter file name: ")
if os.path.isfile(file):
  with open(file) as f:
    r = random.choice(list(f))
    print(r)
else:
  print(file, "Not found")
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/1822e841da)

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
import random
input_file=input("Please enter file name: ")

def rand_word(filename=input_file):    
    with open(filename) as bucket:
        catch_words = [line for line in bucket]    
    if catch_words:
        return random.choice(catch_words).rstrip('\n')
```

Hope it helps!